# Get Workflow Status using Javascript csom SharePoint Online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a requirement to allow/deny a button action from script editor web part based on the workflow status of an item. I tried the below code to get the status of a workflow

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var myID = 'item ID';
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("list name");
var listItem = list.getItemById(myID);   
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Text'>"+myID+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Workflow_x0020_Column_x0020_Name' /></ViewFields></View>");
window.collListItem = list.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(collListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(
function() 
{
var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();    
var status= '';
while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext())
{
 var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
 status = oListItem.get_item('Workflow_x0020_Column_x0020_Name');
}
},
function(){alert("something went wrong");
}

);
```

And the error I would get is

> The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Why this error? Is there a specific way to fetch these columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the internal name of the workflow column. In my case the internal name was restricted to first 8 characters of the workflow column name. Otherwise your code looks good to me. Also the result was a numeric instead of "In Progress" or "Completed" or "Cancelled". Following are the numbers used for the statuses

0 - Starting

1 - Failed on Start

2 - In Progress

3 - Error Occurred

4 - Cancelled

5 - Completed

6 - Failed on Start (Retrying)

7 - Error Occurred (Retrying)

Hope it helps

Comment: for anyone who wondering where these values come from.. it is from `SPWorkflowStatus` enum https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowstatus.aspx

Answer (score 0):

what happens if you change

`context.load(collListItem);`

into

`context.load(collListItem, 'Include(Workflow_x0020_Column_x0020_Name)');`